# Does anybody know how to save and import shortcuts in Windows Media Player Classic?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, media-player

I find myself resetting Windows a lot and the biggest pain in the neck is setting up Media Player's shortcuts. I wish I could simply save my shortcuts and import them later, without inputting them manually every time. Does anybody know, where Media Player Classics stores its shortcuts? Maybe I can just copy-paste that file?

P.S. I'm talking about [K-Lite Codec Player](https://codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm)

Now when I actually tried, it does export them neatly but how do I import them now?

Comment: Do you mean keyboard shortcuts? Or something else?

Comment: May I suggest you to look into VLC Media player as substitute for K-Lite Codec pack? I used to use the K-Lite Mega Codec pack with the mediaplayer classic myself until someone pointed VLC media player to me, which has the codecs buildin and is actively developed. You can also export playlists etc which is the missing functionality you seek

Comment: MPC has nothing to do with the K-Lite Codec Pack. It's just a useful player that's included in that pack and can be installed separately

Comment: Yes I do mean the keyboard shortcuts. I don't want to migrate to a different player without good reasons. The only thing that bugs me about Media Player Classic is inability to export/import custom keyboard shortcuts. And I pretty much use it for watching and listening stuff only, I don't do anything techy or advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press <kbd>O</kbd> to open Options then select *Miscellaneous > Export keys* and your customized shortcuts will be exported. You can also press *Export* to export all settings

[image]

Comment: Thanky you, thank you so much, I have been doing that stupid manual input for too long, it's amazing how easy it was to avoid and also why would they put "Export keys" button in "Miscellaneous" when it should have been placed in "Keys" instead?

Comment: Man, what about importing though?

Comment: the exported file is a \*.reg file so of course just double click it to import to the registry

Comment: Thanks, it never dawned upon me. I tried to open it with Media Player instead, then tried to "Restore" and feed the file to Codec Tweak Tool, looking for "Import Keys" button in Media Player's options, basically I did all the wrong things, while looking in all the wrong places. Thank you for clarifying that important piece for me. P.S. Double clicking it wouldn't have worked for me, as all registry files are automatically opened with notepad on my system.

Comment: @GofunDake it should be opened with regedit.exe by default. You need to reset the \*.reg file association or import from command line by running [`reg import <reg_file>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-import)